# Im trying to get the url of the page that Im in but I can't

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class WorkingWithChrome {

    ChromeDriver driver;
    
    String url = "http://qatechhub.com";
    String urlface = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\fabio\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.get(url);
    
    
    }
    
    public void invokeBrowser2() {
        
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\fabio\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    driver.get(url);
    
    driver.navigate().to(urlface);
    
    driver.navigate().to(url);
    
    driver.getCurrentUrl();
    
    }   
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        WorkingWithChrome wc = new WorkingWithChrome();
        
        wc.invokeBrowser();
        
        wc.invokeBrowser2();
        
}

    driver.quit();
    
    }
    
}
```

Everythink is working, but the "getCurrentUrl()" when it get's to that aprt the code just stop's, the page dosnt even close.
I'v also tried to use `String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();` but it didnt worked, does somebody know's how do I do it ?
(Im new in Selenium and in programming overall)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should add a delay between `driver.navigate().to(url);` and `driver.getCurrentUrl();` to let the page loaded.
Now `driver.getCurrentUrl();` returns a value as a String so you can print it as mentioned with `System.out.println("Current URL : " + driver.getCurrentUrl());`
And after that add `driver.quit();` to quit

Comment: Sorry I didnt explained my self right, the problem is in the `driver.getCurrentUrl()` that dosnet give the Url of the site that the test is in

Comment: Sorry, I was busy :)

Answer (score 0):

As @prophet has mentioned, your `driver.quit();` is misplaced.
Also, `driver.getCurrentUrl();` returns the string. So unless you accept that value in some variable and print it out, you won't know what it's doing.
So please do something like following :

```
public void invokeBrowser2() {
    
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\fabio\\eclipse-workspace\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
    
driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get(url);

driver.navigate().to(urlface);

driver.navigate().to(url);

System.out.println("Current URL : " + driver.getCurrentUrl());

driver.quit();
```

}